# Form action appears in input list?

Tags: php

I have a form with an action eg.

```
<form method="post" action="/save-some-stuff" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
```

I loop through all of the inputs that are sent in the form and save them in a prepared statement, with the input name becoming the database field name.

This works fine.

On the live server this does not work, after some debugging it's looping through all of the inputs fine, but the final input appears to be the forms action:

```
/save-some-stuff
```

I was just wondering if anyone knew why this would be the case?

Comment: Can you paste the HTML source of the entire form, or at least a smaller form exhibiting the misbehavior, as well as the source code of the loop and the inputs it's seeing? And are you making sure to whitelist the field names so that the user can't change fields he shouldn't be allowed to? (Think Bobby Tables.)

Comment: During testing I deleted all fields, I was still getting through the action string server side as an input.

Comment: We will probably need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to reproduce the problem you're seeing.